# How to pass arguments to the list of functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, arguments

Suppose I have a list of functions:

```
functions = {f, g, h, ...}
```

And all of those functions are in form of `f[x_ , y_]`.
For example:

```
f[x_, y_] = x + y;
g[x_, y_] = x^3 + y^2 + 2x;
functions={f,g};
(*Pass x and y for eval?*)
functions[2, 3] (*- Does not work :( *)
Print[MatrixForm[functions[2,3]]] (*The expected result would be a vector
of calculated function values...*)
```

Is there any easy way to pass arguments to the list of functions, so that they all will be evaluated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] = x + y;
g[x_, y_] = x^3 + y^2 + 2 x;
functions = {f, g};
```

Using [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
#[x, y] & /@ functions

(* {x + y, 2 x + x^3 + y^2} *)
```

Using [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html)

```
Through[functions[x, y]] *)

(* {x + y, 2 x + x^3 + y^2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, y_] = x + y;
g[x_, y_] = x^3 + y^2 + 2 x;
functions = {f, g};
```

Using `ComapApply` (new in 14.0)

```
ComapApply[functions] @ {x, y}
```

{x + y, 2 x + x^3 + y^2}

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, y_] = x + y;
g[x_, y_] = x^3 + y^2 + 2  x;
functions = {f, g};
```

---

Using `Thread`:

```
h = Activate[#1 @@@ #2 & @@@ Thread[{#1, Inactive[#2]}]] &;

h[functions, {x, y}]

(*{x + y, 2 x + x^3 + y^2}*)
```